# Java basic CLI calculator

Tags: java, calculator

I want to make calculator for basic mathematical operations. If user enter any other character rather than /,*,-,+ program should exit. but user can only exit with entering other character. program must re show the main menu. 
I tried many times to get pass only mathematical operations. But i can't think a way to do it.

This is my code

```
package com.cv;

import java.util.Scanner;

class Q_04 {
    public static double math(double x, double y, char a) {
        if (a == '/') {
            return x / y;
        } else if (a == '*') {
            return x * y;
        } else if (a == '+') {
            return x + y;
        } else if (a == '-') {
            return x - y;
        }
        return a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        System.out.println(
                "\t*:For multiplication\n\t/:For division\n\t+:For addition\n\t-:For substraction\n\tAny other character:To exit mathematical operation");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String z = sc.nextLine();
        char a = z.charAt(0);
        System.out.print("Enter Number 1: ");
        double x = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter Number 2: ");
        double y = sc.nextDouble();
        double result = 0;
        System.out.println("Answer is " + math(x, y, a));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: Fix your code in the question to make it readable (ie, indent and use the text function for code), it'll make people more likely to read it.

Comment: sorry for bad format i mean i want do mathematical operation for addition multiplication,division and substraction. if user input other character program should exit.

Comment: Exit or redisplay the menu?

Comment: other character to exit but it should re display main menu if user does not enter other character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will not type code but I will write the general idea. First have a while loop which will get the operator. If the operator is valid, then do `break;` otherwise it will repeat the input. Simply doing this will fix your problem. The rest of code will then follow. Be careful of scope (ie, declaring variables inside brackets).

Edit:
If you want to break the program, simply add an if statement `if (!(operator.equals("*") || operator.equals("+") ...`etc. Also, if you really want nice design you can use a hashset to store the operations.

Comment: thanks for the help i figured it using the code you provided